# What is the correct way to make text column not null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm try to create a table in mysql

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
message_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
time_stamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
from INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
to INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
message_content TEXT NOT NULL,
media_id INT,
seen BOOLEAN,
subject TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (message_id),
FOREIGN KEY (from) REFERENCES user (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (to) REFERENCES user (user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES digital_media (media_id),
INDEX (time_stamp, from, to, seen));
```

But I'm getting the error message

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
to INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
message_content TEXT NOT N' at line 4
```

I have no idea what that error message means, I don't understand why the syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to` and `from` are lousy names for columns, because they are SQL key words.

I think this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    message_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time_stamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    from_user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    to_user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    message_content TEXT NOT NULL,
    media_id INT,
    seen BOOLEAN,
    subject TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (message_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (from_user) REFERENCES user (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (to_user) REFERENCES user (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (media_id) REFERENCES digital_media (media_id),
    INDEX (time_stamp, from_user, to_user, seen)
);
```

[It works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8f77249807699c98899899922ab75281) without the foreign key constraints.

Comment: haha I realized this as soon as I posted the question, because of the syntax highlighting in stackoverflow, thanks. It would have been helpful if the error message mentioned that though.